# How can a class know that its super class is Object?

Tags: java

I have a java class "SampleA". How come "SampleA" know that its super class is Object?

Here are my answers,

1. During development, the configuration of JRE in eclipse will automatically say that each class has super class as "Object"
2. During deployment, the class loaders take the responsibility of saying that super class is "Object".

Please correct me.

Comment: If one of the answers helped you then remember to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

During compilation if a superclass is not specified it will be set as `java/lang/Object`. To clarify, this would be exactly the same as if you had declared the class as extending Object:

```
public class Example extends Object {
}
```

All the compiler does is act as a time saver, meaning that you don't have to write the above in **every** class, that's all.

To support this, during execution the verification process of ClassLoading will check that all Classes **definitely** have a superclass. With the single exception of `java/lang/Object`, which has no superclass.

Comment: The compiler sets it during compilation.

Comment: @Jivings, not really. There are many compilers that targets other languages than bytecode. The fact that an class inherits object if nothing else is specified has nothing to do with bytecode or `javac`.

Comment: @aioobe I'm not saying `javac` defines that fact, clearly it's part of the specification. But `javac` will be the entity that sets it if omitted.

Comment: @Jivings, you're answering a question regarding Java, by referring to bytecode, which technically speaking is wrong.

Comment: @aioobe The OP is asking how the JRE knows that a class subclasses `java/lang/Object`, when it is not declared in the source Java code, is he not? My answer only states that this is known because the compiler **fills in the blanks**, setting the superclass to `java/lang/Object` if it is not set.

Comment: It's *not* known because compiler fills in the blanks. It's known because the JLS says so. Your reasoning is backwards. @NPE got it right.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2):

> 4.3.2. The Class Object
>
> The class Object is a superclass (§8.1.4) of all other classes.

Comment: +1. Either the question is ill-phrased or this is currently the *only* correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of compilation, compiler will whether your class is extending some other class using **extends** keyword or not. if not it will set your class as extending **java.lang.object**

You can check this after compiling your class by using **javap** tool provided with JDK

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this code i have tried:

```
public class Example {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Example obj = new Example();
  obj.getSuperClassName();
}
public void getSuperClassName() {
  Class cls = this.getClass();
  System.out.println(cls.getSuperclass());
}
}
```

OutPut:

```
class java.lang.Object
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, just proves it.

Comment: @Jivings So read my first setence "You can also" is there.right ?

Answer (score 0):

JRE is the runtime, Classloaders come into picture during the runtime. Each object refers to the class information. The default super class as per JLS is java.lang.Object. You can find out class hierarchies using 'reflection' in java.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you asking how the class itself can find out what its own superclass is at runtime.

Here's how:

```
    public class Sample .... {

        private boolean extendsObject() {
            return this.getClass().getSuperclass() == Object.class;
        }
```